# Excel rounding with custom tie-break point

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a function in Excel to allow rounding with half-up tie-breaking but at 0.08 instead of 0.05? So there are two cases:

A) Round UP to the nearest $0.10 if it is > $0.08:

```
$15.78 -> $15.80
```

B) Round DOWN to the nearest $0.10 if it is < $0.07:

```
$15.77 -> $15.70
```

Is there a formula that combines both A & B?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you share some sample data to test and fix the issue since the B part of your question doesn't needs to test with IF and part A does need, in this situation any common formula can't works properly!!

Answer (score 1):

In single formula form:

```
B1=ROUND(A1-0.025,1)
```

---

Or the same in user-defined function form:

```
Public Function MyRound(sum As Currency) As Currency
MyRound = Round(sum - 0.025, 1)
End Function
```

Put this code into a common module, than use this funcion in a cell:

```
B1=MyRound(A1)
```

---

In both cases - to view 2 digits after decimal point format the cell properly. If not, trailing zero will be truncated.

Comment: OP needs to test both value with `>0.08` and `<0.07` before Round to nearest value, in this case ROUN DOWN never works since value `15.77` is not `<0.07` , will set to the `FALSE` part !!

Comment: @RajeshS I cannot understand you. OP says: *$15.77 -> $15.70* and *$15.78 -> $15.80* My formulas gives this results exactly. What's wrong?

Comment: Read OP,, **Round UP to the nearest $0.10 cent `if it is > $0.08`,,  $15.78 -> $15.80**, means Roundup `15.78` to `15.80`,,  if `15.78` is `>0.08` ,, And so that for Part B also !!

Comment: Well. Look at the formula. If A1=$15.78, then A1-0.025 gives $15.755, and ROUND($15.755,1) gives $15.80. If A1=$15.77, then A1-0.025 gives $15.745, and ROUND($15.745,1) gives $15.70.

Comment: And what about this  `if it is > $0.08 ` and `< $0.07 ` !!

Comment: @RajeshS I think OP means that "if 2nd digit after decimal point is 7 or lower the whole value must be rounded down up to one digit after decimal point, and if 2nd digit after decimal point is 8 or greater the whole value must be rounded up". And implicitly "the initial value contains only 2 digits after decimal point", so "the 2nd digit" is equal to "the last digit".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92025/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-akina).

Comment: Hi all, I'm super new to Super User and my sincere apologies if I am not being clear. Let me clarify what I mean. 

Yes, I'm looking for a formula that adheres to the following "rules" i.e. 

A) If the **2nd decimal place is 7 cents or lower** (e.g. $15.77), it should **round DOWN to the nearest 1st decimal place / 10 cents** and be $15.80. 

B) If the **2nd decimal place is 8 cents or more** (e.g. $15.78), it should **round UP to the nearest 1st decimal place / 10 cents** and be $15.70

Comment: And on a random note, how can I incorporate spacing to my comments? Without the spacing it's so hard to read! @_@

Comment: @Autumn You can't place line breaks in comments - comments are not meant for extended discussion. They're just meant for quick clarifications. If you'd like to add more detail to your question, you should edit it instead of writing in the comments.

Comment: @Akina Your `ROUND` method works, but it's not clear to the inexperienced reader why. I would recommend adding some more explanation of your method so that future readers can find it useful as well. Also, the fact that you used `0.025` instead of `0.03` implements regular half-up rounding for on-the-fence inputs such as `15.775`, which is not necessarily what OP wanted. You should clarify that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write one! The function you describe can be built out of these elements:

- [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
- [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3)
- [ROUNDUP and ROUNDDOWN functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c)

So you can build your function like so (for an example cell `A1`):

```
= IF(MOD(A1 * 100, 10) >= 8,  # if condition: get the hundredths digit & compare to 8
     ROUNDUP(A1, 1),          # case if true: round up to the nearest 1st decimal place
     ROUNDDOWN(A1, 1)         # case if false: round down to the nearest 1st decimal place
    )
```

(Note that I've assumed that when you said > $0.08 and < $0.07, you actually meant ≥ and ≤, because otherwise the inputs of 0.07 and 0.08 themselves would have no outputs in your function.)

The way this works is that is isolates the hundredths digit of your input and then tests it. For example, if `A1` is `15.77`, you can see the calculations that Excel does by evaluating the function by hand from the inside out:

1. `15.77 * 100         -> 1577`
2. `MOD(1577, 10)       -> 7` (this is the remainder operation)
3. `7 >= 8              -> FALSE`
4. `ROUNDDOWN(15.77, 1) -> 15.7`

This should work even if you have input values that have more than 2 decimal places. Now that you understand how the formula works, you should be able to customise it any time you need to do a special rounding operation. For example, you can look at the 1000ths digit instead by turning `100` to `1000` and changing the second argument of ROUNDUP and ROUNDDOWN from `1` to `2`.

---

To clarify: ≥ isn't a character that Excel understands - generally, computers understand `>=` to mean "greater than or equal to" and `<=` to mean "less than or equal to". I wrote ≥ in the text because humans understand it, but `>=` in the formula because computers only understand that.

Also, I originally misinterpreted your question to mean that you wanted every number less than (or equal to) 0.07 to be rounded down, and every number greater than (or equal to) 0.08 to be rounded up. However, based on your comment, you actually meant that you wanted decimals with 7 in the hundredths place to be rounded down to the nearest tenth, and decimals with 8 in the hundredths place to be rounded up to the nearest tenth. I've updated my formula above accordingly.

And yes, you would use the function like this:

```
=IF(MOD(A1 * 100, 10) >= 8, ROUNDUP(A1, 1), ROUNDDOWN(A1, 1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. I understand the formula but I've some questions:

1) So do I use >= or ≥ ? The latter seems to equate to an error. 

2) So if the amount A1 = $840.32 and I want to round it down as it is ≤$0.08, is the function like:

=IF(A1>=0.08, ROUNDUP(A1,1), ROUNDDOWN(A1,1))

If so, I've tried the above function, and the results wasn't a round down but a round up (which is not what I want @_@).. Not sure why don't it work

Comment: @Autumn Oh, I misread your question! Please see my updated answer.

Comment: So sorry about not using the correct symbols. I've tested it out and it works! Thank u! Wow, how did u pick up ur knowledge in this area? Are there any helpful resources to learn more about such functions?

Comment: Oh and how do u incorporate multiple functions together? Like if I wanted the SUM of something to be rounded up / down, how do I merge the =SUM function with the =IF(MOD(A1 * 100, 10) >= 8, ROUNDUP(A1, 1), ROUNDDOWN(A1, 1)) function so that they appear in the results of both appears in the SAME column?

Comment: @Autumn You can nest functions the same way I nested functions in my answer. So for example, if you wanted to sum the rounded results of A1 and B1, you would do `=SUM(IF(MOD(A1 * 100, 10) >= 8, ROUNDUP(A1, 1), ROUNDDOWN(A1, 1)), IF(MOD(B1 * 100, 10) >= 8, ROUNDUP(B1, 1), ROUNDDOWN(B1, 1)))`. But if you're new to Excel formulas, I recommend you read a guide such as [this one](https://www.shastacoe.org/uploaded/Dept/it/training_docs/Excel/Excel_Introduction_to_Formulas.pdf) so that you can write complicated formulas on your own.

Comment: @Autumn Also, if this answers your question, please click the "Accept answer" checkmark to mark this answer as accepted and resolve the question.

Comment: Sorry.. I meant that I want to apply the function you proposed to a sum of a couple of columns =SUM(G28:G36). How do I do that?

Comment: @Autumn That's nesting under the same principle. You would do `=IF(MOD(SUM(G28:G36) * 100, 10) >= 8, ROUNDUP(SUM(G28:G36), 1), ROUNDDOWN(SUM(G28:G36), 1))` (i.e.: replace all instances of `A1` with the value you want to round).

Comment: Thanks @Niayesh Isky! It works except for 1 figure which wasn't rounded up (not sure why)